# Movie - 80s to 90s Era, Possible Vampire and/or Sci-Fi

Tags: story-identification, movie

I caught the tail end of a strange horror or sci-fi movie and the credits were cut short because of commercials so I never found out the title.

The overall look and feel was campy and of the late 80s to early 90s. The lead female character appeared to be Madonna or someone else with a similar look (ie dark red lipstick, white face cream or powder and blonde hair).

The ending scene that I saw was likely the climax of the movie with the villains being a vampire-like character (similar looking to Al Lewis from the Munsters) and apparently the vampire's (or whatever) daughter. The scene took place in a brightly lit factory of sorts in which old steam press machines were running. The heroes of the movie were gathered in a group adjacent to one of these machines. For some reason unknown to me, the vampire-like villain sat on a wide belt at the front of the machine. He moved mechanically in sync with the machine, though his daughter was distressed by this. The good guys were mostly passive.

Not long after this the vampire character became caught in the machine and began struggling to get free. He was still moving in a stiff, mechanical fashion but was also showing signs of distress. After a short period he was pulled into the machine which was blowing steam as it cycled. A close shot of the machinery showed blood oozing out of its rollers and gears. The vampire's daughter was overwhelmed by the events as the heroes watched with their mouths agape. A large blast of steam was released from the machine likely indicating the death or dissolution of the vampire character and the machine ceased operating.

This was the climax of the scene and the indication that the villain was vanquished. It wasn't clear what became of the vampire's daughter though she may have vanished with her father. Upbeat 80s/90s music began playing and the movie ended.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 3):

I haven’t seen it, and it’s not an exact match, but could you be thinking of [The Mangler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mangler_(film)), based on a [story by Stephen King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mangler)?

It features Robert Englund looking a little like Al Lewis from the Munsters and features a possessed industrial laundry press which kills Englund’s character.

[image: movie poster]

Comment: I just looked at some clips from this movie and it has all of the elements that I described but it seems much darker and gorier than what I recall. Maybe if I see the part where Englund's character is killed it will match.

Comment: Just looked the movie and there must be another version. What I saw about 20 years ago had a smaller but similar machine. The Al Lewis-like character also had some sort of leg braces and that's what caused his mechanical movements which are similar in the Mangler, but the scene of that character getting caught in the machine was considerably longer and in a much better lit environment. In the Mangler we get to see disgusting gore but the movie I saw was much less graphic. However I can now search for anything that was either a takeoff or a precursor to the Mangler.

Comment: @hrh Perhaps there was a made-for-tv version? Robert Englund’s character apparently did wear leg braces. From https://www.denofgeek.com/uk/movies/the-mangler/52273/revisiting-the-film-of-stephen-kings-the-mangler: “He hisses and snarls, clunking around on leg braces that make him look half man, half machine.”

Comment: I also remember the leg braces. There was also an almost unrelated 2002 sequel, and a 2005 sequel which followed directly after the first film.

Comment: I'm beginning to think what I saw was a parody or comedy skit based on the Mangler movie. Since the movie was not well received in its day, its likely it was spoofed. What I saw was a simplified scenario of the actual movie with all of its elements exaggerated: the leg brace movements took up the greater part of the clip and were exaggerated, the villain spent a much more time on the machine than in the movie, the female villain looked like the bride of Frankenstein, the room was very well lit, the other characters appeared as modern young people, the machine was much smaller, etc.

Comment: I started looking for parodies and sketches of the Mangler movie but have found none yet. Not everything makes its way to You Tube. I'll also add to this to my original question.

Comment: Good luck! Post the answer when you find it.